# packagingExcludes not working in maven war plugin

Tags: maven, jar, war, maven-war-plugin

I've following in my pom.xml

```
...
   <groupId>my.org.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservices-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Webapp</name>
<dependencies>
...
</dependecies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/lib/avalon-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/common-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/core-cryptor-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/logging-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/rm-security-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/security-context-shared-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/session-management-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jax*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/opensaml-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/xmlsec-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/xmltooling-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/stax-api-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/axis-saaj-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/axis-jaxrpc-*.jar,
                        %regex[WEB-INF/lib/spring-(?!web).*.jar]
                    </packagingExcludes>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <DisableIBMJAXWSEngine>true</DisableIBMJAXWSEngine>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
```

Now when I do mvn clean install.
I get all jars in the target/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
actually I shouldn't get the jars matching excluded patters like
avalon-*.jar,geronimo-*.jar,aopalliance-*.jar,common-*.jar etc..

Why are these excluded jars coming in WEB_INF/lib??

Comment: Have you defined somewhere overlays? Furthermore packagingExcludes only works for the current project not for the dependencies...Furthermore the dependency to a war makes only sense if you would like to use it as overlay..in other cases you usually use the attached jar of the referenced artifact. An other thing you might need to define the packages you don't like to package into your war as `<scope>provided</scope>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`packagingExcludes` applies to war archive. It has no impact to "exploded" war.

Reference: https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/maven-war-plugin-2.6/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/war/packaging/WarProjectPackagingTask.java#L109

(handleArtifacts( context ) is called regardless of `packagingExcludes`

Answer (score 1):

`packagingExcludes` exclude jar files.

But if application is spring boot,  in the repackaging phase, it puts all the jars back in new package and renames old package to `.war.original` .